# I have two document, how can we create lookup to get results?

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example of a type document:

```
{
    id: 't-123'
    attributes: [
       {
          id: 'a-1',
          type: 'INPUT'
       },
       {
          id: 'a-2',
          type: 'SELECT',
          option: [
             {key: 'DE', label: 'Germany'},
             {key: 'US', label: 'United States'}
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, I have a form collection that references the type collection and stores all filled fields from a user.

Here is an example of a form document:

```
{
    id: 'f-1',
    type: 't-123',
    values: [
      {attribute: 'a-1', value: 'my random string'},
      {attribute: 'a-2', value: 'DE'} 
    ]
}
```

Now, I am trying to query the form collection and automatically add the choosen key/label object from the type collection for fields with type: SELECT.

Here is my desired result:

```
{
    id: 'f-1',
    type: 't-123',
    values: [
      {attribute: 'a-1', value: 'my random string'},
      {attribute: 'a-2', value: {key:'DE', label:'Germany'}} 
    ]
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti



db.form.aggregate([
    {$match: {id: 'f-1'}},
 {$match: {type: 't-123'}},
    {$unwind:"$values"},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'type', 
        localField: 'values.value', 
        foreignField: 'attributes.id', 
        as: 'val'}},
    {$unwind:"$val"},
   
]).pretty()

Comment: and what was the result that came out of this query?

Comment: nothing is coming out.